# Using ScrollViewer inside a FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app with a FlipView. Each FlipView item represents a magazine page (PDF page rendered to bitmap with some overlay).

I need to enable pinch to zoom for all the pages. My FlipView ItemTemplate looks like this

```
<DataTemplate
        x:Key="SinglePageTemplate">
        <ScrollViewer                
            ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <Grid>
                <ProgressRing
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsActive="{Binding IsRendered, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegateConverter}}" />
                <Image
                    Source="{Binding Bitmap}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is that when I zoom out the page and try to move it to the right, it always "jumps" back to the left.

Here is a video showing the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/fv.avi

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: I think I know what's happening here. When you are fully zoomed out, and you try to swipe across, you are actually swiping inside the FlipView item, instead of the parent container.

Comment: I had a very similar problem on Windows 8.1. Almost the same scenario. I found that setting Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBarVisibility to Auto on ScrollViewer helped - but then if the PDF page rendered is bigger than the screen resolution (which usually is, for zooming to work OK), it was rendered too big. So the other thing I did was to limit the Grid's max width to Window.Current.Bounds.Width and max height to that same width multiplied by scale factor based on your magazine's page format. And then it worked.

Comment: Kind of looks like it's hitting [snap points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209553), you might try looking at setting those properties to like MandatorySingle or None

Comment: Igor, you are solved this issue? I faced with same problems..

Comment: @Alexandr try this: http://igrali.com/2015/07/16/why-is-my-zoomable-scrollviewer-snapping-the-image-to-the-left/#.VahJxfXU5hU.twitter

Comment: @igrali thanx for this post, it's works! May be necessary to give a link as answer, so that SO users can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your scrollviewer you have to manually enable scrollbarvisiblity and mode

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
        <Grid>
            <ProgressRing
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsActive="{Binding IsRendered, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegateConverter}}" />
            <Image
                Source="{Binding Bitmap}"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

You can also optionally set the Max/MinZoomFactor to prevent overzoom

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using attached behavior and setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

Below is the code used for attached behavior

```
public class PanAndZoomBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();            
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
            SetElementSize();

        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();            
            Window.Current.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
        }

        private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetElementSize();
        }

        private void SetElementSize()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            AssociatedObject.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            if (AssociatedObject.Content != null)
            {
                FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)AssociatedObject.Content;
                element.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
                element.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            }
        }

    }
```

Apply this behavior to `ScrollViewer`